# How to perform full rotation of 3d model in threejs from pitch, roll and heading?

Tags: three.js, 3d, coordinate-systems

I have a chip that gives me pitch(-90° - 90°), roll(-180° - 180°) and heading(0° - 360°).

I want to mirror any rotations of the object to a model in threejs.

I have made a threejs app that receives pitch, roll and heading,  but I am struggeling with the understanding of how i should rotate the  model, and if its even possible to do this regarding the range of pitch and roll. I Have not found a clear answer to this on the internet.

> Lets say i want to rotate z: -450°, x: 250° and y: -210° at the same
>   time during a 2 second period. I will in my app receive pitch, roll
>   and heading every 100ms with the current rotation and heading.

## Is it this possible to visualize this rotation ?

If yes, what would be the best approach regarding setting the rotation, using local/global axis etc.

I am using tweenjs to perform animations like below.

```js
  new TWEEN.Tween(this.model.rotation)
  .to(
    {
      x: THREE.Math.degToRad(pitch),
      y: THREE.Math.degToRad(roll),
      z: THREE.Math.degToRad(heading)
    },
    150
  )
  .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Linear.None)
  .start();
```

I have good knowledge of frontend programming, but my knowledge with 3d/threejs is not so good.

Answer (score 1):

you could use tween.js(https://github.com/tweenjs/tween.js/) to achieve the desired result and do something like

```
function animateVector3(vectorToAnimate, target, options) {
    options = options || {}
    // get targets from options or set to defaults
    let to = target || new THREE.Vector3(),
        easing = options.easing || TWEEN.Easing.Exponential.InOut,
        duration = options.duration || 2000
    // create the tween
    let tweenVector3 = new TWEEN.Tween(vectorToAnimate)
        .to({x: to.x, y: to.y, z: to.z}, duration)
        .easing(easing)
        .onStart(function(d) {
            if (options.start) {
                options.start(d)
            }
        })
        .onUpdate(function(d) {
            if (options.update) {
                options.update(d)
            }
        })
        .onComplete(function() {
            if (options.finish) options.finish()
        })
    // start the tween
    tweenVector3.start()
    // return the tween in case we want to manipulate it later on
    return tweenVector3
}

const animationOptions = {    
    duration: 2000,
    start: () => {
        this.cameraControls.enable(false)
    },
    finish: () => {
        this.cameraControls.enable(true)
    }
}
// Adjust Yaw object rotation
animateVector3(
// current rotation of the 3d object
    yawObject.rotation,
// desired rotation of the object
    new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, annotation.rotation.z + degToRad(90)),
    animationOptions
)
// Adjust Pitch object rotation
animateVector3(
    pitchObject.rotation,
    new THREE.Vector3(0, degToRad(45), 0),
    animationOptions
)
```

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thans for your answer. I am allready using tweenjs. My biggest problem as described is the understanding of how the rotation of the different axes impacts each other and how to use use the data to perform rotations outside the ranges of pitch and roll